# Multiple assignment in one line

Tags: c, embedded, variable-assignment

I just come across the statement in embedded c (dsPIC33)

```
sample1 = sample2 = 0;
```

Would this mean

```
sample1 = 0;

sample2 = 0;
```

Why do they type it this way? Is this good or bad coding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Equal Signs in One Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244114/two-equal-signs-in-one-line)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Remember that assignment is done right to left, and that they are normal expressions. So from the compilers perspective the line

```
sample1 = sample2 = 0;
```

is the same as

```
sample1 = (sample2 = 0);
```

which is the same as

```
sample2 = 0;
sample1 = sample2;
```

That is, `sample2` is assigned zero, then `sample1` is assigned the value of `sample2`. In practice the same as assigning both to zero as you guessed.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that there's no sequencing in this expression. Which means that it is not correct to assume that `sample2` is assigned first, and that the value assigned to `sample1` is literally read from `sample2`. More correctly, `sample1` is assigned value `0` converted to type of `sample2`. And the assignment to `sample1` can actually happen before assignment to `sample2`.

Comment: Thank for the reply, I would avoid sample1=sample2=0 in the name of readability and sequencing issue as highlighted in AndreyT.

Comment: To this, I would add that `sample2=0` returns an rvalue that is equal to the value assigned in `sample2`. So it is an assignment statement and has a return value in addition, equal to the value it assigned. That returned value (rvalue) is what is being assigned to `sample1`.

Answer (score 12):

Formally, for two variables `t` and `u` of type `T` and `U` respectively

```
T t;
U u;
```

the assignment

```
t = u = X;
```

(where `X` is some value) is interpreted as

```
t = (u = X);
```

and is equivalent to a pair of independent assignments

```
u = X;
t = (U) X;
```

Note that the value of `X` is supposed to reach variable `t` "as if" it has passed through variable `u` first, but there's no requirement for it to literally happen that way. `X` simply has to get converted to type of `u` before being assigned to `t`. The value does not have to be assigned to `u` first and then copied from `u` to `t`. The above two assignments are actually not sequenced and can happen in any order, meaning that

```
t = (U) X;
u = X;
```

is also a valid execution schedule for this expression. (Note that this sequencing freedom is specific to C language, in which the result of an assignment in an rvalue. In C++ assignment evaluates to an lvalue, which requires "chained" assignments to be sequenced.)

There's no way to say whether it is a good or bad programming practice without seeing more context. In cases when the two variables are tightly related (like `x` and `y` coordinate of a point), setting them to some common value using "chained" assignment is actually perfectly good practice (I'd even say "recommended practice"). But when the variables are completely unrelated, then mixing them in a single "chained" assignment is definitely not a good idea. Especially if these variables have different types, which can lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: I believe the standard specifies that the effect is *not* as though the variable was written through first--a distinction which could be extremely important if the variable in question is `volatile`.

Answer (score 10):

I think there is no good answer on C language without actual assembly listing :)

So for a simplistic program:

```
int main() {
        int a, b, c, d;
        a = b = c = d = 0;
        return a;
}
```

I've got this assemly (Kubuntu, gcc 4.8.2, x86_64) with `-O0` option of course ;)

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp

        movl    $0, -16(%rbp)       ; d = 0
        movl    -16(%rbp), %eax     ; 

        movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)     ; c = d
        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax     ;

        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)      ; b = c
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax      ;

        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)      ; a = b
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax      ;

        popq    %rbp

        ret                         ; return %eax, ie. a
```

So gcc is *actually* chaining all the stuff.

Comment: A compiler is free to do any code transformation, that does not change the observable behaviour. Therefore the assembly proves nothing in general. The only thing you can rely on is the c++ standard specification (if the compiler promises to obey the standard).

Answer (score 4):

As noticed earlier,

```
sample1 = sample2 = 0;
```

is equal to

```
sample2 = 0;
sample1 = sample2;
```

The problem is that *[riscy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537629/riscy) asked about embedded c*, which is often used to drive registers directly. Many of microcontroller's registers have a different purpose on read and write operations. So, in gereral case, **it is not the same**, as

```
sample2 = 0;
sample1 = 0;
```

For example, let UDR be a UART data register. Reading from UDR means getting the recieved value from the input buffer, while writing to UDR means putting the desired value into transmit buffer and hitting the communication. In that case,

```
sample = UDR = 0;
```

means the following: a) transmit value of zero using UART (`UDR = 0;`) and b) read input buffer and place data into `sample` value (`sample = UDR;`).

You could see, the behavior of embedded system could be much more complicated than the code writer may expect to be. Use this notation carefully while programming MCUs.

Answer (score 1):

```
sample1 = sample2 = 0;
```

does mean

```
sample1 = 0;
sample2 = 0;
```

if and only if `sample2` is declared earlier.
You can't do this way:

```
int sample1 = sample2 = 0; //sample1 must be declared before assigning 0 to it
```

Answer (score 1):

The results are the same.  Some people prefer chaining assignments if they are all to the same value.  There is nothing wrong with this approach.  Personally, I find this preferable if the variables have closely related meanings.

Answer (score 1):

You can yourself decide that this way of coding is good or bad.

1. Simply see the assembly code for the following lines in your IDE.
2. Then change the code to two separate assignments, and see the differences.

In addition to this, you can also try turning off/on optimizations (both Size & Speed Optimizations) in your compiler to see how that affects the assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the order in which this gets executed is deterministic. The ***operator precedence*** of the = operator guarantees that this is executed right-to-left. In other words, it guarantees that sample2 is given a value before sample1.

*However*, multiple assignments on one row is bad practice and banned by many coding standards (*). First of all, it is not particularly readable (or you wouldn't be asking this question). Second, it is dangerous. If we have for example

```
sample1 = func() + (sample2 = func());
```

then operator precedence guarantees the same order of execution as before (+ has higher precedence than =, therefore the parenthesis). sample2 will get assigned a value before sample1. But unlike operator precedence, the ***order of evaluation of operators*** is not deterministic, it is unspecified behavior. We can't know that the right-most function call is evaluated before the left-most one.

The compiler is free to translate the above to machine code like this:

```
int tmp1 = func();
int tmp2 = func();
sample2 = tmp2;
sample1 = tmp1 + tmp2;
```

If the code depends on func() getting executed in a particular order, then we have created a nasty bug. It may work fine in one place of the program, but break in another part of the same program, even though the code is identical. Because the compiler is free to evaluate sub-expressions in any order it likes.

---

(*) MISRA-C:2004 12.2, MISRA-C:2012 13.4, CERT-C EXP10-C.

Comment: Function calls is just one kind of side-effect that could cause problems. volatile variables, for example hardware registers, will have the same problem as described here.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of this special case ...
suppose b is an array of a structure of the form

```
{
    int foo;
}
```

and let i be an offset in b. Consider the function  realloc_b() returning an int and performing the reallocation of array b. Consider this multiple assignment:

a = (b + i)->foo = realloc_b();

To my experience (b + i) is solved first, let us say it is b_i in the RAM ; then realloc_b() is executed. As realloc_b() changes b in RAM, it results that b_i is no more allocated.

Variable a is well assigned but (b + i)->foo is not because b as been changed
bythe execution of the most left term of the assignment i.e. realloc_b()

This may cause a segmentation fault since b_i is potentially in an unallocated RAM location.

To be bug free, and to have (b + i)->foo equal to a, the one-line assignment must be splitted in two assignments:

```
a = reallocB();
(b + i)->foo = a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding coding style and various coding recommendations see here:
[Readability a=b=c or a=c; b=c;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373171/readability-a-b-c-or-a-c-b-c)

I beleive that by using

```
sample1 = sample2 = 0;
```

some compilers will produce an assembly slightly faster in comparison to 2 assignments:

```
sample1 = 0;
sample2 = 0;
```

specially if you are initializing to a non-zero value. Because, the multiple assignment translates to:

```
sample2 = 0; 
sample1 = sample2;
```

So instead of 2 initializations you do only one and one copy. The speed up (if any) will be tiny but in embedded case every tiny bit counts!

Comment: I doubt there ever existed a compiler that generated different machine code for `sample2=0; sample1=sample2;` and `sample1=sample2=0;`

Comment: @Lundin I was comparing the multiple assignment sampl1=sample2=0; against 2 single ones: sample1=0; sample2=0; Then, I beleive, there is a difference, what do you think?

Comment: I doubt there will be a difference. If there is, then `sample1=0; sample2=0;` is the quicker version (by 1 CPU tick or so...).

Comment: @lundin  I wouldn't say 'never existed' (I've used some pretty crappy compilers in my years), but yeah, any competent modern compiler with optimization turned on probably would generate identical  assembly