# Multiple assignment in one statement for atomic bool variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Following up from [Multiple assignment in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19353686/2436175), I would be curious to know how that would work for atomic data types, in particular with an example with boolean type.

Given:

```
class foo {
    std::atomic<bool> a;
    std::atomic<bool> b;
  public:
    void reset();
    [...] //Other methods that might change a and b
}
```

Is there any difference between:

```
void foo::reset() {
  a = false;
  b = false;
}
```

And:

```
void foo::reset() {
  a = b = false;
}
```

Namely, in the second case, can it happen that after `b` is assigned `false`, another thread set `b` to `true` before `b` is read to assign its value to `a`, so that at the end of the instruction the value of `a` is `true`?

(This would also imply that the latter version is seemingly less efficient)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual compiler output, but `std::atomic::operator=()` is supposed to return the value that is passed to it, so I don't think `a = ...` would actually read the value of `b` at all, it would just receive `false` from `operator=`'s output. Now, in a multithreaded situation, `b` could still be `true` when `reset()` exits, but that is another matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, then that pretty much answer my question, there shouldn't be any difference, otherwise the compiler would be sub-optimal. Thanks! (Sure, at the end of `reset` it can be that `b` is `true` if another thread intervened)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between

```
a = false;
b = false;
```

and

```
a = b = false;
```

if `a` and `b` are atomic. Since assignment is done from right to left, the latter is equivalent to

```
b = false;
a = false; // since atomic::operator= (from above) returns its argument
```

which differs from the very first version because `a` and `b` are atomic and the [assignment is done](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D) as if `std::atomic::store` was called with the memory order `memory_order_seq_cst`. Thereby, the memory model [guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering)

```
a single total modification order of all atomic operations that are so tagged.
```

As a result, a second thread performing atomic loads (`bool a_observed = a.load(); bool b_observed = b.load();`) in the *reverse* order of storing (`a = b = false;`) **may observe the changes in one of the following three ways**:

- old values for both `b` and `a`

  - load `a`, load `b`, <s>store `b`</s>, <s>store `a`</s>
- new value for `b` and old value for `a`

  - store `b`, load `a`, <s>store `a`</s>, load `b`
  - store `b`, load `a`, load `b`, <s>store `a`</s>
  - load `a`, store `b`, <s>store `a`</s>, load `b`
  - load `a`, store `b`, load `b`, <s>store `a`</s>
- new values for both `b` and `a`

  - store `b`, store `a`, load `a`, load `b`

In contrast, the `memory_order_seq_cst` for storing `b` before `a` while (in the other thread) loading `a` before `b` guarantees that **the following is never observed**:

- new value for `a` and old value for `b`

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/kozyTp) for Clang 3.8

Answer (score 1):

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/d4txeD)

There's minimal difference between the two.  The only real difference is that the assignment order is flipped.  If you turn on optimizations, it's indistinguishable.

Comment: Very cool link and website! Actually when using a bit more complex definition, the difference will be in that the order will be preserved even when optimized https://godbolt.org/g/kozyTp