# Does C support multiple assignment of the type a , b = 0, 1 like python does?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, multiple-assignment

```
""" Sample python code representing multiple assignment """
a , b = 0 , 1
print a , b
```

The following code gives output :
0    1
and obviously does not raise any error. Does C support the same?

Comment: No. The closest it comes is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353686/multiple-assignment-in-one-line).

Comment: Often when a language does not support a feature of interest, it means that the language has other ways to approach the higher level problem. What is the need to  do multiple assignments?

Comment: @chux I needed to interchange the values of 3 variables inside the body of my for loop

Comment: You can do something like this: `void AssignValues(int values[], ... );` which would let you implement the first line like this: `int vals[]={0,1};AssignValues(vals, a, b);` but implementing it would be.... nasty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C does not support multiple-assignment, nor has it language-level support for tuples.

```
a, b = 0, 1;
```

The above is, considering  [operator precedence](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), equivalent to:

```
a, (b = 0), 1;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
b = 0;
```

---

The closest C-equivalent to your Python code would be:

```
a = 0, b = 1;
```

That would be needlessly complex and confusing though, thus prefer separating it into two statements for much cleaner code:

```
a = 0;
b = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

No C does not support multiple assignments like this.

Compilation passes since `a , b = 0 , 1` is grouped as `a, (b = 0), 1`. `a` and `1` are no-ops but still valid expressions; the expression is equivalent to

```
b = 0
```

with `a` not changed.

Interestingly, you can achieve your desired notation in C++ with some contrivance and a minor change in the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support list assignments as Python does.  You need to assign to each variable separately:

```
a = 0; b = 1;
```