# Issue with setheap in Heapsort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I'm trying to implement heapsort according to [the original paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/512274.512284) but I don't understand how `INHEAP` works.

```
procedure INHEAP (A, n, in);
    value in; integer n; real in; real array A;
    comment INHEAP is given an array A, elements A[1] to 
        A[n] forming a heap and n≥0. INHEAP adds the element in
        to the heap and adjusts n accordingly. The cycle labeled
        scan may be repeated log₂n times, but on average is repeated
        twice only;
    begin integer i,j;
        i:=n:=n+1;
    scan: if i>1 then
        begin j := i÷2;
            if in<A[j] then
            begin A[i] := A[j];
                i := j;
                go to scan
            end
        end;
        A[i] := in
    end INHEAP;

procedure SETHEAP (A,n) ;
    value n; integer n; real array A;
    comment SETHEAP rearranges the elements A[1] to A[n] to form a heap;
    begin integer j;
        j:=1;
        L: INHEAP(A,j,A[j+1]);
        if j<n then go to L
    end SETHEAP
```

I think the line `i:=n:=n+1;` in `INHEAP` means that `i` is initialized before `n` and `begin integer j;` in `SETHEAP` is supposed to start a loop from 1 to n.

`SETHEAP` calls `INHEAP` with the first and second elements of `A` as arguments. But then why does `INHEAP` add the second element to the heap with `A[i] := in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is written in [ALGOL 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_60). Let me answer your questions/doubts one by one:

> I think the line `i:=n:=n+1;` in INHEAP means that `i` is initialized before `n`

This is just *multiple assignment* like [in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353686/multiple-assignment-in-one-line) and many C-like languages. Assignment should be considered an operator that can be used in an expression and evaluates to the value being assigned. So it is short for:

```
n:=n+1;
i:=n;
```

...in that order.

> I think ... `begin integer j;`  in SETHEAP is supposed to start a loop from 1 to `n`.

Yes, this is a bit obscure, but `j` is incremented by INHEAP, because the `n` parameter is a **reference** parameter (not a **value** parameter like `in`), meaning `n` becomes an *alias* for the `j` variable in `SETHEAP`. And as `INHEAP` increments `n` with the statement `n:=n+1`, the `j` of `SETHEAP` is incremented. If you know C++, then it is like `INHEAP` had declared a parameter `int &n`

> SETHEAP calls INHEAP with the first and second elements of A as arguments.

No, that is a misunderstanding, for two reasons:

- The `INHEAP` procedure is only called with one value at the time, which is the third argument: `A[j+1]`. The second argument `j` is not an array value, but represents the current **size** of the heap. The subarray `A[1...j]` is assumed to be a valid heap. This is true when the first call is made, because an array of size 1 is always a valid heap. The call of `INHEAP` is used to take the next value in the array that is not yet part of the heap and insert it into it, growing the heap.
- After the call to `INHEAP`, `j` has increased (see above), and `A[1...j]` will now have become a valid heap. So the next time `INHEAP` is called it will be called with `j` equal to 2, and passing `A[3]` as third argument, ...etc.

> why does INHEAP add the second element to the heap with A[i] := in?

`INHEAP` must assign `in` *somewhere* in the heap -- that is its role! It must shift some elements in the array to find a right spot for `in` (making room for it), to finally assign it there. Be aware that `n` is not (necessarily) the *size* of the whole `A` array; it is the size of the **subarray** that is already a heap. It can be confusing that both `INHEAP` and `SETHEAP` have a `n` variable, but it is not the same variable: for `SETHEAP`, `n` represents the size of `A`, while for `INHEAP` it represents the size of the subarray that is assumed to be a valid heap.

`INHEAP` does not have to do this assignment for the first element, because there is nothing to check: an array with one element has obviously that element at the only possible position, so there is nothing to move. This is why `INHEAP` is first called with the *second* element as value. And as explained above, `INHEAP` is called also for any element after the second position.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that ``j`` is incremented in the inner loop of ``INHEAP``?

Comment: No, like I wrote: *"`INHEAP` increments `n` with the statement `n:=n+1`*. This happens once, before the loop starts.