# Can't understand purpose of a = b = 0;

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently reading Java A Beginners Guide and in certain points of the book there is a piece of code that confuses me but I can't find an explanation of what it does.

```
int a;
int b;
a = b = 0; //This is the line I don't understand.
```

What I do understand is that the value of 0 is copied into b and then b is copied into a but I don't understand what the point of this would be. Another example would be:

```
Queue(int size) {
   char q[];
   putloc = getloc = 0;
}
```

My question is, what is the point of this piece of code if you're trying to create a first in first out queue or line using an array?

Comment: It's just a more convoluted way of doing two assignments. It's particularly odd in your first case, where it would be more idiomatic to initialize each variable at the point of declaration.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say it's trying to demonstrate that assignment is an expression and returns a value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Readability a=b=c or a=c; b=c;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373171/readability-a-b-c-or-a-c-b-c)

Comment: @YoungHobbit My question is not a duplicate. I ask what the purpose is of the line of code while his question is in reference to readability of his code. I would not be able to understand his question or the answers given to him if I haven't read the answers to my question first.

Comment: @RichardRosa, you should mark one of the answer, if they are helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a shortcut that does exactly the same as this:

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
```

Why `a = b = 0;` works? because the assignment operation is an *expression* that associates from right to left, so `b = 0` executes first, assigning `0` to `b` and then the value in `b` is assigned to `a`, like this: `a = b`. Being explicit with the association order, this is what's happening:

```
(a = (b = 0));
   ^    ^
   |    |
   |    Executes first
   Executes second
```

And why would you do this? well, to make it explicit that both variables have the same value (and save a few keystrokes), but sacrificing some readability in the process. I think it's more clear to declare and assign each variable in a separate line, even if they have the same initial value:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

Comment: OP is asking about what is the reason of doing this rather than simply assign the values in two different lines.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is `a=b=c=d` for the following reasons:

- It is concise, saves lines
- It conveys the concept that (`a/b/c/d`) are initialized to the same thing, that they are related
  However, caveat:

Don't do that if `a/b/c/d` are not related (and just happens to be initialized to 1). You'll reduce the readability of your code. Example:

```
     a=c=1;  // Foo-function related

    b=d=1;  // Bar-function related
```

Chaining assignments like this reduces the flexibility for you in the future to assign different initial values to the variables -- because then you'll have to break them up again.