# Significance of Expression1 = Expression2 = Expression3 in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been doing some Leetcode problems. And i found this particular [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/discuss/57810/Short-Java-solution-without-maps) for this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/). I understood all of it except this line `m[s1.charAt(i)] = m[s2.charAt(i)+256] = i+1;` If someone can explain me this that would be really helpful. Thanks!

**Question**

Given two strings s and t, determine if they are isomorphic.

Two strings s and t are isomorphic if the characters in s can be replaced to get t.

All occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character while preserving the order of characters. No two characters may map to the same character, but a character may map to itself.

***Example 1:***

Input: s = "egg", t = "add"
Output: true

***Example 2:***

Input: s = "foo", t = "bar"
Output: false

***Example 3:***

Input: s = "paper", t = "title"
Output: true

**Solution**

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
        int[] m = new int[512];
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            if (m[s1.charAt(i)] != m[s2.charAt(i)+256]) return false;
            m[s1.charAt(i)] = m[s2.charAt(i)+256] = i+1;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't understand purpose of a = b = 0;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139757/cant-understand-purpose-of-a-b-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in a nutshell doing:

```
m[s1.charAt(i)] = m[s2.charAt(i)+256] = i+1;
```

Is the same as doing:

```
m[s1.charAt(i)] = i+1;
m[s2.charAt(i)+256] = i+1;
```

So if I have:

```
int i = 20;
int y = 10;
i = y = 5;

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(y);
```

The output is:

```
5
5
```

Comment: Oh and i was thinking its something like `m[s1.charAt(i)] = m[s2.charAt(i)+256]` and `m[s2.charAt(i)+256] = i+1;`. Thanks for clearing my doubt!

Comment: @SauravShrivastav To expand, `a = b = c;` is parsed as `a = (b = c);`; the expression `b = c` affects the value of `c` to `b`, and evaluates to that value; then `a = ...` is evaluated and affects that value to `a`.

Comment: @SauravShrivastav In general, when looking at a complex expression that does more than one thing, you have to imagine that there are extra parentheses; and if you know where these parentheses are, you can understand the expression. For instance, `a && b || c` is equivalent to `(a && b) || c`, and `a + b * c` is equivalent to `a + (b * c)`; similarly, `a = b = c` is equivalent to `a = (b = c)`.